# How can I skip Helm/IDO when I want to open Dired?

Tags: helm, dired, ido

When I call Dired with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `Dired`, I got the IDO window with the file structure and when I press Enter, he goes to Dired.

When I disable IDO in Emacs, and I do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `Dired` again, I got the `Helm-dired-mode`. When I confirm the current directory path, the Dired open anyways.

Is there a way to skip IDO/Helm directly when I want to open Dired?

Comment: What happens when you just use a key bound to `dired`? If `C-x d` is co-opted by one of those modes, then consider redefining it (or defining some other key) as `dired` in those mode maps.

Comment: I bounded a key to Dired already, but then I still get IDO/Helm window. Same with the <kbd>C-x d</kbd>. I found another solution, see my answer below. Thanks for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. After inspecting it further, I found the option `dired-jump` which does the same as `dired` but without the IDO/Helm.

The docstring tells the following

```
Jump to Dired buffer corresponding to current buffer.
If in a file, Dired the current directory and move to file's line.
If in Dired already, pop up a level and goto old directory's line.
In case the proper Dired file line cannot be found, refresh the dired
buffer and try again.
When OTHER-WINDOW is non-nil, jump to Dired buffer in other window.
Interactively with prefix argument, read FILE-NAME and
move to its line in dired.
```

Thanks for the help anyway! :)

Comment: Always nice to find something already built-in. We get so giddy with all the extensions that we forget such hidden gems.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable helm completion for some specific command when `helm-mode` is on, you can modify the user option `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`, for example, for you request

```lisp
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist
             '(dired . nil))
```

you can read its docstring to learn how it works.

Answer (score 2):

```cl
(require 'dired-x)
```

Then press <kbd>C-x C-j</kbd> to open `dired` in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Having trouble myself going from spacemacs home-buffer to dired on ~ with the default keybinding SPC-a-d  for `M-x 'ido-dired`  (Too many possible completions.)

So I override this keybinding.

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "a d" 'dired-jump)  ;; overrides ido-dired
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "a D" 'dired-jump-other-window)
```